Why did Jesus call Nathanael an "Israelite in whom there is no deceit"?

John 1:47 (ESV, emphasis mine)


Jesus saw Nathanael coming toward him and said of him, “Behold, an
Israelite indeed, in whom there is no deceit!”

This seems like a significant statement for Jesus to make. It stands out in the narrative, and it raises the question. Why did Jesus specifically call Nathanael a man without deceit?

@curiousdannii I did not see that post. Thank you. The answer has some relevance. I may still keep it open though and let others decide as the focus of my question is a bit different. My question seeks more to understand the significance of Jesus’ statement about Nathanael’s character. If anything I was looking for a more exegetical answer. The other question is more focused on the meaning of the Greek word δόλος and its implications in the context of the passage.

That's why I suggested it rather than just immediately closing it :)

so how did it come to be closed? Oh wait, it seems that @Dottard  has this power by virtue of his being an expert in the Book of John. I didn't realize that was a thing.

@DanFefferman - I did not realize I had that "power".  I though I was simply voting to close but it was instantly closed.
